# Programmatically picking an inequality operator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to perform actions based on input from a config file.  In the config, there will be specifications for a signal, a comparison, and a value.  I'd like to translate that comparison string into a choice of inequality operator.  Right now, this looks like

```py
def compute_mask(self, signal, comparator, value, df):
    if comparator == '<':
        mask = df[signal] < value
    elif comparator == '<=':
        mask = df[signal] <= value
    elif comparator == '=':
        mask = df[signal] == value
    elif comparator == '>=':
        mask = df[signal] >= value
    elif comparator == '>':
        mask = df[signal] > value
    elif comparator == '!=':
        mask = df[signal] != value
    
    return mask
```

In other applications, I was able to do something like

```py
func = {
    'a': func_a,
    'b': func_b,
    'c': func_c
}.get(func_choice)
func(value_to_process)
```

in order to easily avoid having to repeat code over and over.  How would I go about doing the same thing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `operator` module to get functions equivalent to each of the operators.

```
import operator

funcs = {
    '<': operator.lt,
    '<=': operator.le,
    '=': operator.eq,
    '>': operator.gt,
    '>=': operator.ge,
    '!=': operator.ne
}

def compute_mask(self, signal, comparator, value, df):
    return funcs[comparator](df[signal], value)
```

Comment: Huh, for some reason I was thinking this didn't work with pandas.  That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I saw a neat solution like this recently where you list the cases as lamdbas in a dict, then you fetch the lamdba from the dict and call it in the return statement. In your case it would be something like this:

```py
def compute_mask(signal, comparator, value, df):
    cases = {
        '<': lambda df, signal, value: df[signal] < value
        '<=': lambda df, signal, value: df[signal] <= value
        '==': lambda df, signal, value: df[signal] == value
        '>=': lambda df, signal, value: df[signal] >= value
        '>': lambda df, signal, value: df[signal] > value
        '!=': lambda df, signal, value: df[signal] != value
    }
    return cases[comparator](df, signal, value)
```

Comment: that's better then I managed so far but I think it still has a lot of reused code, which is what I'm trying to get away from.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, and i also agree with you. i upvoted Barmars answer as well! The general pattern that i like is by listing cases in a dict which contains callables, then you fetch and call it in the return statement

Comment: Since you're always using the same arguments, you don't need parameters in the lambdas, so it could be just `lambda: df[signal] < value`

Comment: And then `return cases[comparator]()`