# A better way of achieving the same?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is this the most efficient way of doing this? It works but I wonder if there's a better way of doing the same thing. The nested if after selecting the operation doesn't look very clean even tho it works.

```
des = " "

while des != "n" or "no":
# Operators
add = "+"
minus = "-"
multiply = "*"
divide = "/"

# Prompt
n1 = int(input("1: "))
operator_selection_prompt = input('Select operation (+, -, *, /): ')
n2 = int(input("2: "))

if(operator_selection_prompt == add):
    r = n1 + n2
    print(r)
    des = input("Re-Run? (y/n): ")
    if des not in ('n', 'no', 'y', 'yes'):
        print('no valid')
        break
elif(operator_selection_prompt == minus ):
    r = n1 - n2
    print(r)
    des = input("Re-Run? (y/n): ")
    if des not in ('n', 'no', 'y', 'yes'):
        print('no valid')
        break
elif(operator_selection_prompt == multiply):
    r = n1 * n2
    print(r)
    des = input("Re-Run? (y/n): ")
    if des not in ('n', 'no', 'y', 'yes'):
        print('no valid')
        break
elif(operator_selection_prompt == divide):
    r = n1 // n2
    print(r)
    des = input("Re-Run? (y/n): ")
    if des not in ('n', 'no', 'y', 'yes'):
        print('no valid')
        break
```

Comment: This belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Given the number of outright errors in the code, I would say "no, this is not optimal".

Comment: "most efficient way of doing this"—Doing *what*?

Comment: I suppose you are looking for something like this. Check answer on this question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66125362/programmatically-picking-an-inequality-operator/66125562?noredirect=1#comment116908980_66125562

Comment: @orlp Thank you.

Comment: The if elif chain is fine but why do you copy the print until the break ? Just put it once, unindent it so that it is not inside the ifs. It is a common issue in beginner programmers not to grasp the idea of putting code *after* the if, not *in* the if action.

Answer (score 1):

[Programmatically picking an inequality operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66125362/programmatically-picking-an-inequality-operator/66125562?noredirect=1#comment116908980_66125562)

check that for reference. Would be something like this in your case:

```py
import operator

des = ""

operations = {
    "+": operator.add,
    "-": operator.sub,
    "/": operator.truediv,
    "*": operator.mul,
}

while des != "n" or "no":
    n1 = int(input("1: "))
    operator_selection_prompt = input('Select operation (+, -, *, /): ')
    n2 = int(input("2: "))
    print(operations[operator_selection_prompt](n1, n2))
    des = input("Re-Run? (y/n): ")
```

Comment: Here it works, but if I input anything other than n it continues

Comment: Exactly, based on the condition on the while loop. Just to edit as you want it, i just focused on the elifs to make it more slim. Edited answer to remove if with break since the while loop handles that part, making it even shorter

Comment: Got it brother! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Only one time doing the print and test-break. Constants in uppercase. Add else so that r is always defined. Removed unnecessary parenthesis.

@tbjorch goes one step further but this looks like an exercise for a beginner so I'll leave it to basic stuff.

```
des = " "

while des != "n" or "no":
    # Operators
    ADD = "+"
    MINUS = "-"
    MULTIPLY = "*"
    DIVIDE = "/"

    # Prompt
    n1 = int(input("1: "))
    operator_selection_prompt = input('Select operation (+, -, *, /): ')
    n2 = int(input("2: "))

    if operator_selection_prompt == ADD:
        r = n1 + n2
    elif operator_selection_prompt == MINUS:
        r = n1 - n2
    elif operator_selection_prompt == MULTIPLY:
        r = n1 * n2
    elif operator_selection_prompt == DIVIDE:
        r = n1 // n2
    else:
        r = None  # needed otherwise entering "%" would cause r to be undefined for print(r)
    print(r)
    des = input("Re-Run? (y/n): ")
    if des not in ('n', 'no', 'y', 'yes'):
        print('no valid')
        break
```

Comment: This also works, thanks :D .

Answer (score 0):

This is the way that I would go about it:

```
while True :

    n1 = input ("1: ")
    operator = input ('Select operation (+, -, *, /): ')
    n2 = input ("2: ")

    if n1.isnumeric () and n2.isnumeric () and operator in ('+', '-', '*', '/') :
        print (eval (f'{n1}{operator}{n2}'))
    else : print ('Error!')

    des = input("Re-Run? (y/n): ")
    if des not in ('y', 'yes', 'Y', 'Yes') :
        break
```